# Нужна ли запятая в первой части предложения

Tags: запятые

Направляю Вам скорректированные критерии, определяющие преждевременный вывод из эксплуатации электродвигателей 6 кВ, контролируемых по показателям надёжности в ПАО «ТехМаш».

Comment: Какую именно запятую Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Какая именно? Пунктуация в вашем примере верная, обе имеющиеся запятые нужны, а какие-то еще просто некуда ставить.